# Blazor Webassemby: Object reference not set to an instance of an object i

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly, ant-design-blazor

The page throws a NullReferenceException when the table are filled with data. All the data are filled (mocked data). There is no case of null values. It throws an exception, when it tried to call "context.consultant.FullName".
I have also debugged it. All data are set.

**Page:**

```
  @if (list != null)
  {
        <AntDesign.Table @ref="table"
                         TItem="Customer"
                         DataSource="@list">

        <Column @bind-Field="@context.Id" />
        <Column @bind-Field="@context.Name"  />
        <Column @bind-Field="@context.LastName"  />
        
        <Column Field="@context.consultant.FullName"  />  --> throws here the exception.
    </AntDesign.Table>
}
@code{

 ...

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    list = GetCustomers()
  } 

   private List<Customer> GetCustomers()
   {
     var consultant = new Consultant
            {
                ID = "183",
                FirstName = "Service",
                LastName = "Team";
            };
            
            
        return new Customer[]
        {
            new(){
            ID = "3",
            FirstName = "Peter",
            LastName = "Fox";
            Consultant = consultant
            },
            new(){
            ID = "4",
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Fox";
            Consultant = consultant
            },
        }.ToList();
    
    }
```

**Models:**

```
public Customer{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Consultant Consultant { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChangedDate { get; set; }
}

public record Consultant
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName {
        get => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
>   crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>       Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Test.Client.Pages.Customer.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<BuildRenderTree>b__21(RenderTreeBuilder
> __builder2)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32
> sequence, RenderFragment fragment)    at
> AntDesign.Table`1[[Test.Shared.Models.Customer, Roma.Portal.Shared,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].<BuildRenderTree>b__255_5(RenderTreeBuilder
> __builder6)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32
> sequence, RenderFragment fragment)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CascadingValue`1[[System.Boolean,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)   
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder
> batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry
> renderQueueEntry)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
> }
```

Solution Found:

It was a AntDesign Problem. This was missing:

```
 <Column  TData="string?" DataIndex ="Consultant.FullName" />
```

> Instead of using @bind-Field, you can specify the property to be bound
> by setting the data type TData and the data index string DataIndex,
> which can bind descendant properties. The type of the column data is
> the same as the definition of TData.
>
> When the bound property is ValueType and is Nullable, TData should be
> set to Nullable type. For example:  or "
> DataIndex="prop1" />.
>
> When Column uses DataIndex, Table's OnChange event parameter
> QuerModel.SortModel[].FieldName is equal to DataIndex.
>
> See path-based-property-access for details of the access modes
> supported by DataIndex.

Comment: _"All the data are filled"_ is obviously not true. We can't debug code (or data) we can't see.

Comment: Replace `list = (await client.GetCustomerAsync()).ToList();` with code that fills a small list. Make sure it still shows the error and then [edit] the question.

Comment: I have edit a new private function, that fills the list. It still shows the same error in browser

Comment: I think it has something to do with the AntDesign...

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar issue but with Server side blazor. What I finally figured was to create a new model with the parameters you want to bind to the table from both classes, in your case Customer and Consultant say like so;

````
    
   //from customer 
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //from consultant
    public string ConsFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ConsLastName { get; set; }
    public string ConsFullName {
        get => $"{ConsFirstName} {ConsLastName}";
   
}```

then use it to map your result to the table by assigning the desired parameters from customer and consultant to the new MappingModel
````